# Referencing 2 different data contexts in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my MainWindow I have this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ActiveRecord />
</Window.DataContext>
```

In my usercontrol I have this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <search:CustomerSearch />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

before i added this 'local' binding i would reference the 'modular' binding in my usercontrol like this:

```
var vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel.ActiveRecord;
```

but because i want to reference 2 different bindings it appears to not work any more.  What  I mean by that is that I populate the ActiveRecord with values but when i navigate to another form these values are null.

Comment: If you need them to have references to each other, don't compose them in xaml. Do it in the window's codebehind, or use an IoC to instantiate them.

Comment: HI Will.  Thanks for your comment, I never used IOC pattern so will Google it now.  I will take your point about declaring from within code behind.  I will see if that makes difference